# How to use if condition in twig template  with twig tags inside in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to use this

```
{% if not app.request.isXmlHttpRequest %}
   {% block body %}
   <div>{{ form_widget(form) }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

And i get error that unexpected enfif tag after block tag

Comment: Maybe it's the universe trying to tell you that logic doesn't belong in templates? Just kidding. Kind of.

Comment: @rdlowrey , may be universe telling the sensio labs to remove all logical conditions in next version of TWIG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps try adding the closing `{% endblock %}` tag, eg

```
{% if not app.request.isXmlHttpRequest %}
   {% block body %}
       <div>{{ form_widget(form) }}</div>
   {% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Problem is i can't use endblock  because i have the other content between the body tags which i want to display in ajax request

Comment: @user1596900 then move the `block` tags outside the conditional statement